# How to use a Snowflake-Schema in Mondrian?

Tags: schema, olap, dimension, mondrian, snowflake-schema

I have a fact table that has a `RESOURCE_ID` that links to the resource table. A resource has a role, that it self is a resource.

```
.--FACTTABLE--.  
| IDENTIFIER  |    .--RESOURCE---.
| RESOURCE_ID |----| RESOURCE_ID |    .--RESOURCE---.
                   | ROLE_ID     |----| RESOURCE_ID |
                                      | TITLE       |
```

Now i want to create a dimension `ROLE` that contains the attribute `TITLE`.

How to do this? Example with Mondrian 4 Schema would be appreciated.

*I know there is a `<Link>` for the `<PhysicalSchema>` and the `<ForeignKeyLink>` for the `<DimensionLinks>` but i don't know how to use them properly.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found out how to do this.

---

### Solve cycles

Since role and resource are both from the table `RESOURCE`, Mondrian couldn't handle that and came into a cycle.

I solved this with an alias for the `RESOURCE` table:

```
<Table name="resource" schema="public" keyColumn="id" alias="role"/>
```

### Link tables

To let Mondrian know which resource belongs to which role, you need to link both tables.

Therefor it's important that the resource table has a key:

```
<Table name="resource" schema="public" keyColumn="id"/>
```

Now you can link the resource to it's role:

```
<Link target='resource' source='role' foreignKeyColumn='role_id'/>
```

### Define the dimension

The confusing thing at first, is that the role dimension needs the table resource. That's because the fact table only knows the `RESOURCE_ID` and not the `ROLE_ID`. But since every resource is linked to it's role, you can use the Attributes to define the role specific fields.

```
<Dimension name="Role" table="resource" key="ID">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute name="ID" keyColumn="id" hasHierarchy="false"/>
        <Attribute name="Title" table="role" keyColumn="title"/>
    </Attributes>
</Dimension>
```

### Use the dimension

To use the dimension we have to use the dimension in the cubes dimensions and link the `RESOURCE_ID` of the fact table to the role dimension.

Useage:

```
<Dimension source="Role"/>
```

DimensionLinks:

```
<ForeignKeyLink dimension="Role" foreignKeyColumn="resource_id"/>
```